# Kotlin activity with n columns of text

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, spinner, composable

I have a spinner with names, when selecting a name I want it to open a Text for each Child, below is, for example, the Text with profession. Is this possible in Jetpack compose? (Two Text columns interspersed by n Child Columns)?

Create a form with variable format according to the informed profile.